# svelte <input /> examples script reactivity failing when html reactivity works

Tags: svelte

Taking examples such as found here
https://svelte.dev/examples/select-bindings
or here
https://svelte.dev/repl/387bf1bbbd134d0193df33ddf712fd40?version=3.14.1

when copy pasting as is ... and running the input works, the file is selected and the `{# if ...}` in the html behaves. but the code in the `<script />` is not responding reactivley so i cannot log any thing out console wise.

When the page reloads i can see that files is set to undefined and the script runs - which was suprising. But then when a file is selected the script does not run (nothing is logged to console) yet the html updates.

example:

```
<script>
    let files;

    $: {
        console.log('here');
        console.log(files);
    }
</script>

<label for="many">Upload multiple files of any type:</label>
<input bind:files id="many" multiple type="file" />

{#if files}
    {JSON.stringify(files)}
    <h2>Selected files:</h2>
    {#each Array.from(files) as file}
        <p>{file.name} ({file.size} bytes)</p>
    {/each}
{/if}
```

this also fails

```
    $: if (files && files[0]) {
        console.log('here');
        console.log(files);
    }
```

the latter also fails if i move the `if` inside the `{}`

MoreInfo:

If i change the `console.log` into an alert() in the function then it logs ... so its `console.log` not behaving as expected not reactivity

....   so why that in my example but not in the given examples ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This component already seems to work, you need the console from developer tools in your web browser to view the log output.

You seem to be using a later version with Sveltekit. Since that update enables server-side rendering, the IDE console you see only logs from server context-- only the client web browser has context of a selected file, until it's actually sent over the wire to the server.

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options